# Neo4jClient out of memory exception in processing small dataset

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

I am using neo4j community edition to store my data that fetch from tweeter API, until now I collect around 200000 tweets and store them in neo4j database (each as a node). I am using neo4jclient to connect to neo4j in my c# application.
When I run code below to get this nodes it cause an out of memory exception !!!

```
var client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"));
        client.Connect();
        var result = client.Cypher.Match("tweet").Return(tweet => tweet.As<Tweets>()).Results;
```

I've searched a lot and wonder that others talk about dataset which contains 50 millions nodes and so many relationship !!! But my simple small dataset cause this kind of exception.
what I need is how to handle this ? actually I want to process each node and add some more attribute to each !

Also I should mention that my neo4j web interface can't process this data and just show where it limit to small number !!!

Comment: Where do you get OutOfMemory exception? In your C# app or on the Neo4j server?

Comment: @MicTech In the last line of the above code !!! var result ...

Comment: The problem is not with Neo4j. You are trying load all tweets into memory of your program. You should avoid that. I suggest to do some filtering.

Comment: @MicTech I want to add an attribute to all the tweets ! how should I do something like this ?

Comment: Could you please describe what you trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not attempt to return a very large number of tweets at one time, since that can easily cause your program to run out of memory (even if neo4j has no problems). And, since you only want to set some properties, returning all the tweets is not necessary anyway.

The following is a very simple example of how to set the `foo` property of all the tweets to the same value, without returning any results.

```
var client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"));
client.Connect();
var result = client.Cypher
  .Match("tweet")
  .Set("tweet.foo = {foo}")
  .WithParam("foo", 123)
  .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

Comment: my problem is I don't have the foo property in my node and actually I need to add and set this property ! Is this code also add the property even if it doesn't exists?

Comment: Yes. (However, if you later wanted to return the `foo` property in a `Tweets` object, you will have to add a definition of it to your Tweets class.)

Comment: I will check it tomorrow , thanks a lot for your answer, I mark this as best answer.

Comment: is there anyway to get one property and set the new one according to this ? I mean I want to set the new attribute according to one of the existing property :( what should I do ?

Comment: I should mention I need some string processing on that attribute to generate the new ones :(